# How to exclude modules using AWS "sam build" for nodejs?

Tags: aws-sam-cli

Using the `sam build` command I was expecting not to include the `aws-sdk` package as the Node.js Lambda runtime already includes it.

As I understood the `sam build` for nodejs is a port of `claudia pack` command from `claudiajs`, but I do not see any `--no-optional-dependencies` flag when I run `sam build --help`.

I tried installing `aws-sdk` as an optional dependency but still included.

Is there a way to exclude a dependency from the `node_modules` directory using the `sam build` command?

Comment: I had the same issue and made aws-sdk a dev dependency. I think it is only needed for unit testing or calling your code outside of sam local. I see the optional depency included even when I try using claudia pack directly. (It looks like "--no-optional-dependencies" will install a package listed in optionalDependencies as long as package-lock.json is present and it doesn't list the dependency with optional=true. That seems to happen if the optional dependency is actually installed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experimentation I found a couple of options:

1. Install aws-sdk as a dev dependency

```
npm i -D aws-sdk
```

2. Install aws-sdk as an optional dependency and then use a .npmrc file to disable installing optional decencies on npm install

```
npm i -O aws-sdk
```

```
# .npmrc
optional = false
```

My folder structure looks something like this:

```
-- project
   |-- lambdas
   |   |-- lambda1
   |   |   |-- node_modules
   |   |   |   `-- ...
   |   |   |-- .npmrc
   |   |   |-- index.js
   |   |   |-- package-lock.json
   |   |   `-- package.json
   |   `-- lambda2
   |       |-- node_modules
   |       |   `-- ...
   |       |-- .npmrc
   |       |-- index.js
   |       |-- package-lock.json
   |       `-- package.json
   |-- package-lock.json
   |-- package.json
   `-- template.yml
```

Running sam build in both these instances bundles the packages without the unwanted dependencies for me.

Answer (score 1):

McShaman answer is valid for NPM 6.

NPM config has changed in NPM 7 - "optional" was removed.

You should use "omit" instead, to ignore optional dependencies:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#omit

```
# .npmrc
omit=optional
```